# get div height in percent subtracted of other div height which is in pixel

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get percentage of a side bar height of which height is subtracted from a header of which height is in pixel.

```
<!--html-->
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="sidebar"></div>

<!--css-->
body{padding: 0; margin: 0;}
#header {position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: yellow;}
#sidebar {position: fixed; width: 20%; background-color: blue; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; }

<!--js-->
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var bodyHeight = document.getElementByTagName("body").height();
    var headerHeight = document.getElementById("header").height();
    var sideBarHeight = (bodyHeight - headerHeight) / bodyHeight;
    $("#sidebar").css("height",sideBarHeight);
});
```

Here is my fiddle to check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/Herza/7ks1qet1/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a percentage you should convert the pixels back to a percentage.

Is this what you meant?

https://jsfiddle.net/7fkfvwrf/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    
    var bodyHeight = $(document).height();
    var headerHeight = $("#header").height();
    var sideBarHeightPercentage = 100 / bodyHeight * (bodyHeight - headerHeight);
    $("#sidebar").css("height",sideBarHeightPercentage + "%");
});
```

```css
body{padding: 0; margin: 0;}
#header {position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: yellow;}
#sidebar {position: fixed; width: 20%; background-color: blue; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; }
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS should be able to do do this:

```css
body{padding: 0; margin: 0;}
#header {position: fixed; width: 100%; background-color: yellow; 
  top:0;
  height: 50px;
}
#sidebar {position: fixed; width: 20%; background-color: blue; bottom: 0px; left: 0px;
  
  top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
```

or even with clac()

```css
body{padding: 0; margin: 0;}
#header {position: fixed; width: 100%; background-color: yellow; 
  top:0;
  height: 50px;
}
#sidebar {position: fixed; width: 20%; background-color: blue; bottom: 0px; left: 0px;
  
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
```

you can run both snippets in fullpage mode and resize you window to check on it.

Beside the CSS/JS trouble you add, i'm not too sure it is a good idea, header and sidebar might be too small for content and in fixed position , what overflow off screen is unreachable ...

Comment: Thanks, dude! It works as well! I didn't know CSS could do this! Thanks again!